# Why did my printer's nozzle dig itself into my print?

Tags: g-code, creality-ender-3

I just completed my first print on my Ender-3 and when the print finalized itself the nozzle didn't elevate itself to clear away from the piece. I watched as the nozzle slowly lowered itself into my print and destroy it. Here is the gcode generated by Slic3r used:

```
; Filament-specific end gcode
G4 ; wait
M221 S100
M106 S0 ; turn off cooling fan
M104 S0 ; turn off extruder
M140 S0 ; turn off bed
G91
G1 F1800 E-3
G90
G1 Z{z_offset+min(layer_z+30, max_print_height)}{endif} ; Move print head up
G28 X0 ; home x and y axis
G1 Y180; Remove Print Position
M84 ; disable motors
M300 S2600 P100; Beep
; filament used = 24040.5mm (57.8cm3)
; total filament cost = 0.0
```

[image: preview of the destruction]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using **incorrect commands** in your end-code for the **incorrect tool** with respect to the print head raise.

Slic3r has no knowledge of the maximum printer height (as in variable `max_print_height`) because there is **no input field to specify this**, as can be seen in this partial screenshot:

[image: Slic3r print area settings]

However, in Slic3r PE (Prusa Edition), there is a possibility to enter such a value, as seen in the following partial screenshot:

[image: Slic3r PE print volume settings]

Note that in both editions, the `Bed shape` interface is equivalent when `Set...` is pressed:
[image: Slic3r and Slic3r PE bed area settings]

To use the raising of the head, respecting the maximum print height, in **Slic3r PE**, you need to add the following line:

```
{if layer_z < max_print_height}G1 Z{z_offset+min(layer_z+60, max_print_height)}{endif}
```

This will parse fine in **Slic3r PE**, but not in **Slic3r** (as `max_print_height` is not known).

If you want such a command in **Slic3r**, you need to enter (for a printer with a maximum print height of 240 mm):

```
G1 Z{[z_offset]+min([layer_z]+3, 240)}
```

results in Slic3r for a 20x20x20 mm calibration cube with a zero `z_offset` to:

```
G1 Z23
```

Comment: But there shouldn't be a need to change the Z-pos at all!  Once the print is done, the head should be able to clear the last layer applied and move to X=0,Y=0 . No need to do anything else, right?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Have you never seen the straight ironing line that some slicers generate over the top layer? Raising the head prevents that.

Comment: @Oscar  I have to admit I have not.  Certainly a good reason, then, to do a small relative-Z move first.

Answer (score 1):

Your print end code should have read something akin to this:

```
; Filament sy end gcode
G4 ; wait
M221 S100
M106 S0 ; turn off cooling fan
M104 S0 ; turn off extruder
M140 S0 ; turn off bed

; End code
G1 F1800 E-3 ; retract 3 mm
G1 Z30 ; Move print head up 30mm
G28 X0 ; home x and y axis
M84 ; disable motors
M300 S2600 P100; Beep
```

The problem with your end code is the `G90` for **absolute** measurements together with the formula `G1 Z{z_offset+min(layer_z+30, max_print_height)}{endif}` to set the height. The printer itself doesn't calculate anything. That what it doesn't interpret, it ignores, interpreting that whole thing as something crazy like `G1 Z30` to force the printer to go to Absolute 30 mm above absolute 0. To fix it,  your slicer would need to calculate `{z_offset+min(layer_z+30, max_print_height)}` for the printer - which seems to come out to 30mm above the print and then an if-statement that is not started anywhere.

Going up 30 mm can be much easier be done by staying in `G91 ; relative measurements` and calling `G1 Z30` to go up another 30 mm, though this might be too high for the printer frame.

Comment: The G-code in the slic3r reads:
G90
{if layer_z < max_print_height}G1 Z{z_offset+min(layer_z+30, max_print_height)}{endif} ; Move print head up

I notice that 'if' statement doesn't seem to be present in the output G-code file. Is this the problem?

Comment: @JonathanGallant-Mills yes, it is a problem. you should also have some else... or just skip that

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me several years ago. My print was a fairly tall part for my delta printer, about 220 mm. In many previous prints, the print head would always go up after finishing, but what I didn't know was that the Slic3r finish print routine specified an absolute Z height of about 200 mm. When the tall part finished, the still-hot print head moved down and ruined the top of the print.

After figuring out that the routine had an absolute reference, I replaced it with a relative movement 20 mm up. It's worked fine since then. An easy fix.